# Show that $\int_G (f*g)(x) (-x,\gamma) dx = \int_G (-x,\gamma)dx \int_G f(x-y)g(y)dy = \int_G g(y) (-y,\gamma)dy \int_G f(x-y)(-x+y,\gamma)dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, convolution

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian (LCA) group.

A complex function $\gamma$ on a LCA group $G$ is called a character of $G$ if $|\gamma(x)| = 1$ for all $x \in G$ and satisfies 
$$\gamma(x+y) = \gamma(x) \gamma(y).$$
$\Gamma$ is the set of all continuous characters of $G$, called the dual group of  $G,$ with operation $+$ given by 
$$(\gamma_1 + \gamma_2)(x) = \gamma_1(x) \gamma_2(x)$$

Denote $(x,\gamma) = \gamma(x).$

Recall that convolution of $f$ and $g$ is defined as 
$$(f*g)(x) = \int_G f(x-y)g(y) dy.$$

The following is extracted from 'Fourier Analysis on Groups' by Rudin, page $7:$

> (Theorem $1.2.2$) If $\gamma \in \Gamma$ and if
>   $$\hat{f}(\gamma) = \int_G f(x) (-x,\gamma) dx \,\,\, (f \in L^1(G)).$$
>   Then the map $f \mapsto \hat{f}(\gamma)$ is a complex homomorphism of $L^1(G),$ and is not identically $0.$
>   Conversely, every non-zero complex homomorphism of $L^1(G)$ is obtained in this way, and distinct character induce distinct homomorphisms.

Proof (partial):

Suppose $f,g\in L^1(G)$ and $k = f*g.$ Then 
$$\hat{k}(\gamma) = \int_G (f*g)(x) (-x,\gamma) dx = \int_G (-x,\gamma)dx \int_G f(x-y)g(y)dy $$
$$= \int_G g(y) (-y,\gamma)dy \int_G f(x-y)(-x+y,\gamma)dx = \hat{g}(\gamma)\hat{f}(\gamma).$$

> Question: How to obtain second and third equalities, that is, 
>   $$\int_G (f*g)(x) (-x,\gamma) dx \stackrel{1}{=} \int_G (-x,\gamma)dx \int_G f(x-y)g(y)dy $$
>   $$\stackrel{2}{=} \int_G g(y) (-y,\gamma)dy \int_G f(x-y)(-x+y,\gamma)dx?$$

I have no idea how to obtain $1$ and $2.$
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Identity 1) is by the definition of convolution and 2) is Fubini and the relation $1=(y,\gamma)(-y,\gamma)$. The notation of the integral is confusing, I see it usually in physics; I think this is the source of your confusion.